# Why the font size won't change with browser zoom in?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web

In most of websites, while I change the zoom level of browsers, the font size will also increase and help user to see them. For some reasons, that just won't work on my new website. While I change the zoom level of the browser, everything changes but all font size keep the same. Is there a css or html property that I can use to control this behavior? Thanks

here is an example:
http://ca.skywatcher.com/index.php

Comment: @Because not everyone is able to browse your site exactly the way you see it. It's about accessibility for people with eyesight problems or various other reasons.

Comment: @JamWaffles Thanks for letting us know what doesn't interest you. I can imagine letting users zoom in to read the text on my websites to be a pretty crucial feature, but you've shown me the errors of my ways.

Comment: @Doozer I know that, I just think that time, effort and worry should be spent elsewhere catering to larger user minorities.

Comment: I have fixed this issue, thanks!!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is that you have set `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` for the body in `layout.css`. Changing it to `-webkit-text-size-adjust: auto;` allows the zooming of the fonts along with the page.

Edit: Corrected the CSS. Should be `auto` not `0`

Comment: Good find!  This explains why the problem doesn't occur with Firefox.  Here's an article on `-webkit-text-size-adjust`: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201011/beware_of_-webkit-text-size-adjustnone/

Comment: @jdigital Haha, I was just reading that one. I wanted to know why that works too.

Answer (score 7):

Fonts using a specific pixel size are not relative (along with several others). Zooming changes that relative information.

From http://www.westciv.com/style_master/academy/css_tutorial/properties/values.html

```
Name        Abbrev. Explanation                             Relative?
em          em      The height of a font                    yes
ex          ex      The height of the letter x in a font    yes
pica        pc      1 pica is 12 points                     no
point       pt      1/72 of an inch                         no
pixel       px      One dot on a screen                     no
millimeter  mm      Printing unit                           no
centimeter  cm      Printing unit                           no
inch        in      Printing unit                           no
```

Comment: Modern browsers will zoom everything, regardless of the units specified for the font.  See the answer from @Lycha

Comment: @jdigital Strange... I can no longer reproduced what I've seen a few days ago... (I remember I checked that the Computed Style in the Developer Tools did NOT have any -webkit entries when zoom didn't work). And now the sites zoom fine... You can delete your comment on my previous comment and I'll delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a fixed-point width for your font-size settings (e.g.: pixels), then your font size will remain unchanged when the user zooms. If you want the font to enlarge or diminish when the user zooms in/out, then consider using `em` as your unit (1 em = 100% of the default font size on the user's machine).

Comment: Zooming changes the font-size as well.