# Client is complaining his site is "too small" when he's zoomed out

Tags: css

A client of mine is kicking up a fuss about his site displaying "too small".

[This is the site in question](http://www.robotwp.com/hyper/clark-smith/) and to me it looks fine.

He attached a screenshot and it's clear that he's only experiencing this problem because he's "zoomed out".

Is there a way to keep the text size the same regardless of whether the browser is zoomed in or not?

Comment: LOL so what he expects on **ZOOM OUT?**

Comment: ask the client if the text is too large when he zooms in, and mention that they should not be zooming in or out to view the website correctly.

Comment: Nice. Id suggest using a service like http://browsershots.org/ to give evidence of how he is wrong/right

Comment: I think the best option would be to argue your point with the client rather than trying to regulate the font size on zoom in and zoom out because that wouldn't be much fun to resolve at all.

Comment: Even though I understand your frustration, please leave out the rant and concentrate on making a *question* for SO.

Comment: @deceze Seems fine to me. Providing context ≠ rant. It also seems that the client is a bit of an idiot and a “solution” has to take that into account.

Comment: @Konrad At least the question title should be a question, not a statement about what his client feels.

Answer (score 1):

There is a question with your problem but in reverse, the person cannot get their page to zoom the text in or out:

[Why the font size won't change with browser zoom in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907760/why-the-font-size-wont-change-with-browser-zoom-in)

It states in the answers listed that they had set

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

And this was causing their problem, maybe add it to yours and see how it works?

EDIT:

Someone also posted an article on that same question with regards to the use of the code above, it can be found here:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201011/beware_of_-webkit-text-size-adjustnone/

How it helps.