# Change font size on each browser zoom out level

Tags: html, css, media-queries, font-size

I want change font-size on each browser zoom out level,

**for example:**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 0.25) {
    div {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

@media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 0.50) {
    div {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 100) {
    div {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}
```

above codes not working..

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907760/why-the-font-size-wont-change-with-browser-zoom-in

Comment: `0.50` in one query and `100` in another, is that correct?

Comment: @MrLister it's just a simple example!

Comment: @user2167382 i saw this before.. wasn't my solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have set -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; for the body in layout.css. Changing it to -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; allows the zooming of the fonts along with the page.